# How can I pass value of variable from one job to next job in pipeline in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Am I able to pass value from variable that I created in one job to next job so I can do some checks of that value in next job of the same stage ?
I would like to have first job that creates some variable and then assigns value to that variable and next job, in same stage that would do check of that value ? I need this for specific use case in my pipeline ?

I was going through the documentation on GitLab and I couldn't find any recource that would help me with solving this case ?

Any help with this would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do this by using the `dotenv` file artifact. You'll create a file in one job that has a set of values in it like this:

```
FIRST_VAR=1234
SECOND_VAR=hello_world
```

Then set that as a [dotenv type artifact according to the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv), and that will make downstream jobs have those variables be set.

A pseudo-example `.gitlab-ci.yml` file would be:

```yaml
generate-dot-env-file:
  image: alpine
  script:
    - echo "FIRST_VAR=1234" >> my_file
    - echo "SECOND_VAR=hello_world" >> my_file
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: my_file

read-dot-env-file:
  image: alpine
  # needed so it reads the report/artifacts
  needs: generate-dot-env-file
  script:
    - echo $FIRST_VAR #outputs 1234
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Is this solution applicable for the jobs in the same stage ?

Comment: You would need to express a `needs` dependency between them to ensure that the job defining the artifact completed before the dependent job started, but it would work within the same stage otherwise, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to solve the problem I had by following your instructions, plus I was able to refactor it to have less stages which is great ! :)

Comment: Perfect! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Do you have a yml example to do this?

Comment: @tzg - I added one to the answer. I hope that helps.